# Query to calculate Average time between first visit and first purchase across users using ANSI SQL or postgres SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Consider the following database schema for an e-commerce website:
Given the following schema of tables:
**Event table (no index / key) - contains event data recorded when an event occurs:**

```
event_name [VARCHAR] 
user_id [VARCHAR]
time [TIMESTAMP]
```

**Transaction table (no index / key) - contains transaction data for item_id [VARCHAR]**

```
quantity [INTEGER]
price [NUMERIC]
user_id [VARCHAR]
time [TIMESTAMP]
```

Please Provide detailed queries to retrieve the answers to the following questions:

- Average time between first visit and first purchase across users. [consider `event name` ‘**visit**’]
- Median and 80 percentile time between first visit and first purchase across users. [consider `event name` ‘**visit**’]
- Average time between first visit and purchase per `item_id`.
- Median and 80 percentile time between first visit and purchase item per `item_id`.
- Given an `item_id` [consider `item_id` ‘**shoe_01**’], retrieve an ordered list of items that are most likely to be purchased by a user who purchased the item.

For all the above, consider ANSI SQL or Postgres SQL standards, and optimise for edge cases & performance.

Comment: please format your code statements!

Comment: For assignments, you should attempt to answer the question yourself and have specific questions about aspects that you are unclear on.

Comment: For the first question: make a SELECT over your two tables JOINing the user_id with the AVG() function. for your third question: take solution for #1 and add a GROUP clause. For the fourth question: Again a SELECT over all two tables via user_id ORDER BY. But what do you mean "most likely to be purchased by a user who purchased the item"??

Comment: Are you really sure you want ANSI SQL? When it comes to date/time there's only one or perhaps two products that are ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Thanks Radinator, last question is to perform pattren recognition

Comment: @Gordon, I wanna cross verify my answer before submitting hence posted:)

Comment: @Jarlh, i need queries in ANSI or in Postgres standards

Comment: And with an ANSI compliant query, which dbms product will you use?

Comment: Oracle DBMS product

Comment: Won't work... Oracle is not ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, then why do you have Postgres in the subject?